# DbContext instance System.ObjectDisposedException in .Net Web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have a Asp.Net web app that used for validation, a scanner is connected to it through serial port and whenever a qr code is scanned, It gets the data and the page is refreshed and uses the new data gotten from the qr code. My problem now is that whenever I scan, and data is received in my controller function, which is shown below.

```
public void mySerialPort_Data(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {            
            try
            {
                string data = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
                barcode = data.Split(";");
                codeValue = barcode[0].Substring(barcode[0].IndexOf(":") +1);
                SelectedPN(pn_No);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            
        }
```

I call the controller function of the current page in the function above **SelectedPN()** and this function I think is supposed to load and refresh the data I got from the qr code, but I keep getting an error.
Below is the SelectedPN() function that is called in the function above

```
 public ActionResult SelectedPN(String nameobj)
        {
            
            pn_No= nameobj;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

            _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(mySerialPort_Data);

            if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    _serialPort.Open();

                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }

            ViewBag.check9 = codeValue;
            List <double> newList = new List<double>();
            var num = 0;
            var bill = 4;

            
            var categoryFromDb = _db.Categories1.Where(j => j.MaterialNumber == nameobj);
            foreach (var obj in categoryFromDb) { 
                newList.Add(obj.ComponentNumber);
            }
            num = newList.Count;
            var duplicates = newList.GroupBy(x => x)
                            .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
                            .Distinct()
                            .ToList();
           
            
            ViewBag.check1 = check;
            //testlist.Add(Convert.ToDouble(data1.X2));
            ViewBag.check1 = check;
            ViewBag.check2 = "background-color: #00FF00;";
            ViewBag.check3 = 3;
            ViewBag.check4 = num;
            //ViewBag.check5 = '';
            ViewBag.update = num;
            changeValue = num;
            ViewBag.check6 = testlist;
            ViewBag.check7 = duplicates;



            return View( categoryFromDb );
        }
```

The error is that it says the instance of my dbContext has been disposed and therefore i cannot use it.

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'ApplicationDbContext'.'
```

**What I have tried**
I found online in a post that ServiceLiftime of DbContext is set to *Scoped* by default, and it disposes the instance once it is used and I have to change it to **ServiceLifetime.Transient** to be able to resuse the instance, but this did not work. I still got the same error again

Below is where I set the ServiceLiftime

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
    ), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

I would appreciate any help on how to solve this problem.

**EDIT**

This is my complete controller

```
namespace WA4.Controllers
{
    
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        
        static SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        
        public IEnumerable<Category> categoryFromDb;
        

        public CategoryController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            getPorts();
            IEnumerable<Category> objCategoryList = _db.Categories1;
            return View(objCategoryList);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SelectedPN(String nameobj)
        {
            
            pn_No= nameobj;
            
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

            _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(mySerialPort_Data);

            if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    _serialPort.Open();

                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }

            ViewBag.check9 = codeValue;
            List <double> newList = new List<double>();
            var num = 0;
            var bill = 4;




            
                categoryFromDb = _db.Categories1.Where(j => j.MaterialNumber == nameobj);
            

                foreach (var obj in categoryFromDb) {
                    newList.Add(obj.ComponentNumber);
                }
            num = newList.Count;
            var duplicates = newList.GroupBy(x => x)
                            .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
                            .Distinct()
                            .ToList();
               
        
            return View( categoryFromDb );
            
        }
```

And below is my DbContext.cs content

```
using WA4.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WA4.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried using the solution @Walsharoo suggested but I got an error instead

```
 using (ApplicationDbContext _db = new() )
            {
                categoryFromDb = _db.Categories1.Where(j => j.MaterialNumber == nameobj);
            

                foreach (var obj in categoryFromDb) {
                    newList.Add(obj.ComponentNumber);
                }
            num = newList.Count;
            var duplicates = newList.GroupBy(x => x)
                            .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
                            .Distinct()
                            .ToList();
```

**Error**

```
InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.Initialize(IServiceProvider scopedProvider, DbContextOptions contextOptions, DbContext context)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet<TEntity>.get_EntityType()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet<TEntity>.get_EntityQueryable()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet<TEntity>.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
WA4.Controllers.CategoryController.SelectedPN(string nameobj)
lambda_method86(Closure , object , object[] )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

**EDIT**

This is the stack trace after following the suggestion of @Roberto Ferraris

```
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()   Unknown
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.ContextServices.get() Unknown
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.ChangeTracker.get()   Unknown
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.CompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator.GenerateCacheKeyCore(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression query, bool async) Unknown
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalCompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator.GenerateCacheKeyCore(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression query, bool async)    Unknown
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerCompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator.GenerateCacheKey(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression query, bool async)   Unknown
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WA4.Models.Category>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression query) Unknown
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<WA4.Models.Category>.GetEnumerator() Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Collections.Generic.List<WA4.Models.Category>.List(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WA4.Models.Category> collection)    Unknown
    System.Linq.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<WA4.Models.Category>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WA4.Models.Category> source)  Unknown
>   WA4.dll!WA4.Controllers.CategoryController.SelectedPN(string nameobj) Line 87   C#
    WA4.dll!WA4.Controllers.CategoryController.mySerialPort_Data(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) Line 315 C#
    System.IO.Ports.dll!System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.CatchReceivedEvents(object src, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)   Unknown
    System.IO.Ports.dll!System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.EventLoopRunner.CallReceiveEvents(object state)    Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback..cctor.AnonymousMethod__6_0(System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback quwi)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunForThreadPoolUnsafe<System.__Canon>(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Action<System.__Canon> callback, System.__Canon state)   Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.Execute() Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart() Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()  Unknown
```

Comment: From [The DbContext lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#the-dbcontext-lifetime)  we see "It is very important to dispose the DbContext after use." Besides, in your controller, you miss the definition for `_db`, and have a try to  refer the document to create and register the ApplicationDbContext.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean, can you please expatiate.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you have disposed your datacontext.

Try using a new instance of it.

```
ienumerable<object> categoryFromDb;

using (DataClasses1DataContext _db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    categoryFromDb = _db.Categories1.Where(j => j.MaterialNumber == nameobj);
}

foreach (var obj in categoryFromDb)
    newList.Add(obj.ComponentNumber);

num = newList.Count;
var duplicates = newList.GroupBy(x => x).SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1)).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't seem to work. I have edited my question and added my controller to show info

Comment: I tried the solution you suggested but I got an error I don't really understand

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you return  `categoryFromDb` :

```cs
return View( categoryFromDb );
```

The `categoryFromDb` in fact is not a collection of elements, but it is simply a query definition:

```cs
categoryFromDb = _db.Categories1.Where(j => j.MaterialNumber == nameobj);
```

Linq use a deferred execution (see [Introduction to LINQ Queries (C#) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries))  so each time you use this variable a query is execute against the database.

Since you return the query with `View(categoryFromDb)` it will be resolved when the `ActionResult` is executed (and not at the return statement) and tipically at this time de db context was already disposed.

I suggest to change your code to include something like `ToArray` or `ToList`, so that the query is executed and the results are loaded in the variable:

```cs
categoryFromDb = _db.Categories1.Where(j => j.MaterialNumber == nameobj).ToList();
```

Comment: I just tried this method, but i got the same error:     `Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application.`

Comment: At wich point of the code you receive the exception? In the assignment of the categoryFromDb variable? Can you share the stack trace?
From the exception that you include in the post it seems that the exception was thrown from the AuthorizationMiddleware

Comment: Also don't use Transient as Lifetime, use Scope, the dbContext will be instantiated once for each request.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I have removed the **Transient as lifetime** and i believe **Scoped** is the default if none is set. Also, I have added the stack trace as an edit to the question

Comment: Ok, now it's clear what happens. The error was thrown in the `mySerialPort_Data` because it is executed after the Post request was already processed, and db context disposed.
Anyway simply recall the action doesn't do nothing client side. Simply re-execute the code, but this time outside a request so there is no db context instantiated. 

The Post method of Http doesn't provide push notifications by itself, you need to provide data with something like SignalR.

Comment: I got the first part of your explanation, but I don't quite understand the latter part. What do you mean by SignalR?  (sorry for so many questions, but like I said, I am new to this so please indulge me.)

Comment: Sorry Joe for the late response. SignalR is a library for ASP.NET that allow to implements push functionality. See [Introduction to SignalR (MS Learn)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)